# how to reset part of form in orbeon

Tags: web-services, orbeon, formbuilder

Is it possible to simply reset form controls (inluded checkboxes, selections, repeatable compontents, text inputs)? (when web service return some data I want to reset some part of form to get possilibity to add new data via web service - I invented it to replace nested repeatable grids).

Answer (score 1):

There is not much that can't be done by writing custom XForms code, but out of the box it's only possible to clear the *whole* form with the "Clear" button.